# If Condition for Both Integer and float

Tags: c#, if-statement, integer, conditional-statements

Here I have one problem my text box allowed only integer and float value. If any thing else it will give an error message. Please find my code below.

```
if (!int.TryParse(x, out value))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("","eeroro message");
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: u want to show error if textbox is not int or float?

Comment: `if (!int.TryParse(x, out value) && !float.TryParse(x, out value) )
               {
                   ModelState.AddModelError("","eeroro message");
               }` can use double.tryparse also for float

Comment: I think it's enough to check only for float. If it's not an int, it surely isn't a float either (all ints are floats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if (!int.TryParse(x, out value) && !float.TryParse(x, out value) ) 
{ 
  ModelState.AddModelError("","eeroro message"); 

}
```

Here the model state error message will be added if both parse failed. If anyone of them success it will skip the if condition

Comment: I think it's enough to check only for float. If it's not an int, it surely isn't a float either (all ints are also floats). Also, you can't use the same out value for both int.TryParse and float.TryParse. It will cause a compile time exception.